# calculating checksum when uploading a file

Tags: php

I am uploading files to server. I found a function like

```
$sha1 = sha1_file($filename);
```

at http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/8/15/0

So I was wonder whether or not `$filename` should point to the actual file with path or just the filename?

`$_FILES['upload']['name']` will do it right?

Comment: This is what learning is. Those how oppose such questions saying the asker should figure the answer on their own do not take into account that hearing the answer from a fellow (or guru) is much more assuring than testing while you doubt your test method at the same time.

Comment: This is not learning, this is spoon feeding. Give a man a fish, feed him for a day, etc etc.

Comment: We have all been spoon fed but may not remember it anymore! Seriously, even in the context of learning to program. In this context there are two board groups, those who have had a structured, academic learning experience, and those who have taught themselves picking bits here and there (the orphans if you may). It is very hard for the former group to realize how important is the impact of the informal and unconscious micro-learning opportunities they've had. Let's don't deny the latter group similar opportunities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path to uploaded file is `$_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]`

so if you haven't moved the uploaded file the function call would be

```
$sha1 = sha1_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Read up on the basics of [handling file uploads in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Preferably, do a `move_uploaded_file()` first, then in the target location, fetch the checksum.

Comment: as a matter of fact, there is no difference, when to calculate. Temporary location just as good as target one.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, wrong.
Why can't you just try it and see?

According to [manual page](http://php.net/features.upload), the path to uploaded file is in the $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] variable

Comment: @pradeep when getting errors, please *always* quote them in full. Everything else is wasting your fellow users' time.

Comment: @pradeep well if you get an error, can't you conclude yourself, if $_FILES['upload']['name'] will do it or not? Looks like it's not?

Comment: I totally disagree with the attitude, but this doesn't deserve a -1 (or a +1 for that matter). Shrapnel is never nice, but often right.  The OP should get off his laurels and get to testing rather than asking such naive questions.

Comment: @stereofrog actually you can't tell what is the intention here. Please, add "in my humble assumption" to your further expressions.